# Nested SQL Queries using multiple tables and pymssql in Python

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

I have 2 tables with information about contestant races that I need to organize into one clean output statement (not a tuple or list) that only gives each unique contestant along with their region, average race time, and a count of how many races they competed in.

Using `"SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;"` returns the following tables I have to work with:
Tables, Column_Names

```
('Outcome', 'ID')
('Outcome', 'RaceID')
('Outcome', 'RaceTime')
('Outcome', 'ResultID')
('Contestant', 'Age')
('Contestant', 'Region')
('Contestant', 'ID')
('Contestant', 'Name')
('Contestant', 'Gender')
```

Here is what I have so far. I can get the first part to join the tables and return the individual columns that I need, but they aren't in the right format and it is including each race instead of an aggregate of each contestant.

```
#This block returns all the columns needed from all tables with INNER JOIN
cursor.execute("SELECT Contestant.Name, Contestant.Region, Outcome.RaceTime, Outcome.RaceID FROM Contestant INNER JOIN Outcome ON Contestant.ID=Outcome.ID;")
for row in cursor:
    print(row[0],"   ", row[1],"   ", row[2],"   ", row[3])
```

The first couple lines that this Query returns are below but they don't have  the full region name, not an average of racetime, and showing the raceID instead of count of races.

```
Smith   PNW   64.59   1.0
Kohl   SW   50.3   1.0
```

If this was working the way I needed, it would return this way with 3 spaces between variables, full region name, and average of all the contestants race times, and a count of how many races they were in. This would also then need to be ordered by average time from highest to lowest.

```
Smith   Pacific Northwest   59.454   7
Kohl   Southwest   54.203   4
```

Here are other lines I have that will return separately everything else that I need to put into the clean table:

```
#The following each does a part of what needs to happen with the columns data ultimately
cursor.execute("SELECT Region, CASE WHEN Region = 'PNW' THEN 'Pacific Northwest' ELSE 'Southwest' END AS Region_Long FROM Contestant;") #Updates abbreviated region names to full names
for row in cursor:
    print(row[1]) #prints out just the full region names
cursor.execute("SELECT ID, AVG(RaceTime) FROM Outcome GROUP BY ID ORDER BY AVG(RaceTime) DESC;") #Calculates each Contestants's avg race time
for row in cursor:
    print(row[1])
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT RaceID) FROM Outcome GROUP BY ID;") #Counts how many races each Contestant had
for row in cursor:
    print(row[0])
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to put all of this together to make it output how I need it to instead of just outputting each part separately.

Comment: Ideally, the `ID` in Outcome table should be named `ContestantID` to avoid confusion with a primary key which `ResultID` may be. Outcome appears to be a one-to-many relation of contestants and results. Interesting you need to run `COUNT DISTINCT` as if contestants can run same race (i.e., same `RaceID`) multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run an aggregate query that joins needed tables, runs both aggregates, and groups by contestant and region.

```sql
SELECT c.[ID] AS Contestant_ID,
       c.[Name] AS Contestant_Name, 
       c.Region, 
       CASE c.Region
          WHEN 'PNW' THEN 'Pacific Northwest'
          WHEN 'SW' THEN 'Southwest'
          ELSE c.Region 
       END AS Region_Long,
       AVG(o.RaceTime) AS Avg_Race_Time,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.RaceID) AS Race_Count
FROM Contestant c
INNER JOIN Outcome o ON c.ID = o.ID
GROUP BY c.[ID],
         c.[Name],
         c.Region, 
         CASE c.Region
            WHEN 'PNW' THEN 'Pacific Northwest'
            WHEN 'SW' THEN 'Southwest'
            ELSE c.Region 
         END
ORDER BY AVG(o.RaceTime) DESC
```

Python implementation

```py
sql = """SELECT c.[ID] AS Contestant_ID,
                c.[Name] AS Contestant_Name, 
                c.Region, 
                CASE c.Region
                   WHEN 'PNW' THEN 'Pacific Northwest'
                   WHEN 'SW' THEN 'Southwest'
                   ELSE c.Region 
                END AS Region_Long,
                AVG(o.RaceTime) AS Avg_Race_Time,
                COUNT(DISTINCT o.RaceID) AS Race_Count
         FROM Contestant c
         INNER JOIN Outcome o ON c.ID = o.ID
         GROUP BY c.[ID],
                  c.[Name],
                  c.Region, 
                  CASE c.Region
                     WHEN 'PNW' THEN 'Pacific Northwest'
                     WHEN 'SW' THEN 'Southwest'
                     ELSE c.Region 
                  END
         ORDER BY AVG(o.RaceTime) DESC
      """

cursor.execute(sql)

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Comment: This throws a TypeError: execute() takes at most 2 positional arguments (6 given). I'm assuming this is because I'm needing to do this in Python's pymssql rather than just SQL

Comment: I only showed the SQL (to capture highlighting) and not Python implementation. The idea is to place this *single* SQL in a Python string (like you did for all other SQL attempts) and then pass it into execution: `execute(my_sql_str)`. Don't call `execute()` by itself without any args. See [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75129169/revisions) using Python's triple quote string assignment for multiple lines.